# can we create more than one inner broadcast receiver in different activities

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, smsmanager

Can we create more than one broadcast receiver in different activities. 
like every activity has 1 broadcast receiver and also register in manifest. 
i tried and work good but my query is that it good or not and it consuming more memory ? or how can i eliminate it, by creating one broadcast receiver which handles all processes. like i want to store different SMS my application has different kinds of status which i receive via SMS . so i created different broadcast receiver at different activities. 
I also put some code for receiver

```
public static class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        String a = "";
        DataBaseHandler db;
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            db = new DataBaseHandler(context);

            if (!intent.getAction().equals(
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
                return;
            else if (intent != null) {
                Bundle bndl = intent.getExtras();
                SmsMessage[] msg = null;
                String abc = "";
                String msgs = "";

                if (null != bndl) { // if start
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bndl.get("pdus");
                    msg = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                        msg[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        if (msg[i].getOriginatingAddress().equals("15555215556")) 
                        {
                            abc = msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                            msgs = msg[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                        }
                    }
                    if (abc != "" && ! msgs.equals("")) 
                    { // inner if start
                        String[] str_split = msgs.split("\\n|:|,");
                        String temp = str_split[0].substring(str_split[0].lastIndexOf(' ') + 1).trim();
                        ArrayList<String> numb =new ArrayList<String>();
                        if (temp.equals("DEACTIVATED") || temp.equals("  ACTIVATED") ) 
                        {
                            String numbs ;                          
                            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                                numbs = str_split[j].substring(str_split[j].lastIndexOf(',') + 1).trim();
                                numb.add(numbs);
                            }

                            for (int i = 1; i < numb.size(); i++)
                                a += i + " " + numb.get(i) + "\n";                          
                            db.update_sys_pwd(temp);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }// inner if over
                } // if over
            }
        } // onReceive over
    }
```

Please help me because i never work with telephony ,GSM API .
or how can i create 1 receiver which handles all other receiver for update data. like to register all broadcast receiver inside 1 receiver and then it set to manifest file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please help me i need your answer.

Comment: Is it the same kind of broadcast that you want to add to all your activity classes?

Comment: yeah this class will add to all my activities. and i receive different sms and different sms contain different status which are used in different activities.

Comment: and also i have progress bars to which will stop when i receive sms . it also put in this class. and i have to store status in database and then based on status my activities are display it.

Comment: You can handle multiple broadcasts in one broadcast receiver class. And to be able to notify multiple Activities you can setup Listeners in the respective Activity Classes to receive updates.

Comment: can u give me little demo because i search on google how to add multiple broadcast receiver inside one broadcast receiver but i couldn't find any thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to let single BroadcastReceiver hanle single event (SOLID principle). However, you can register several receivers, each receiving different event.
There is another problem in your code - BroadcastReceiver is running on main thread and Android suppose that code in BroadcastReceiver will finish very fast. You should not do any long running actions (writing to database) in it. Instead, get received data and start IntentService for processing that data by passing received values via Intent

Comment: so can u tell me what is i'm doing now is right or wrong ? or you can suggest me other ideas because i never work with it so i don't have any ideas.

Comment: If you register BroadcastReceiver in Manifest, it will be triggered by Android all the time, even when your app is closed. On the other hand, when you register and unregister it dynamically (in .onpause() and .onResume()) methods), it will receive events only when that screen is active

Comment: no i my status codes are receive at any time there is not fix time so i cannot unregister receiver